# Return Nested Key in Groovy

Tags: groovy, dictionary, nested

I am trying to determine the best way to return nested key values using groovy.  If I have a map:

```
def map = [
   OrganizationName: 'SampleTest',
   Address: [
      Street: '123 Sample St',
      PostalCode: '00000',
   ]
]
```

Is there a way to return all of the keys? `OrganizationName`, `OrganizationURL`, `Address.Street`, `Address.PostalCode`? If I didn't have an map within a map I could use map.keySet() as String[].  Should I just loop through each key and see if it is an instanceof another map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no such method You're looking for in groovy. You need to do it using `instanceof` and probably a recursive method.

Comment: I assumed so but I think I would ask.  Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

The Groovy libraries don't provide a method for this, but you can write your own. Here's an example that you can copy-paste into the Groovy console

```
List<String> getNestedMapKeys(Map map, String keyPrefix = '') {
  def result = []

  map.each { key, value ->
    if (value instanceof Map) {
      result += getNestedMapKeys(value, keyPrefix += "$key.")
    } else {
      result << "$keyPrefix$key"
    }
  }

  result
}

// test it out
def map = [
   OrganizationName: 'SampleTest',
   Address: [
      Street: '123 Sample St',
      PostalCode: '00000',
   ]
]

assert ['OrganizationName', 'Address.Street', 'Address.PostalCode'] == getNestedMapKeys(map)
```

Comment: Change the "if" block to:
`result += getNestedMapKeys(value, keyPrefix = "$key.")`
`keyPrefix = ''`

Answer (score 1):

Use Following generic recursion Method To generate the list of all nested map keys

```
def getListOfKeys(def map, String prefix,def listOfKeys){
    if(map instanceof Map){

        map.each { key, value->
            if(prefix.isEmpty()){
                listOfKeys<<key
            }else{
                listOfKeys<< prefix+"."+key
            }

            if(value instanceof List){

                List list = value

                list.eachWithIndex { item, index ->
                    if(prefix.isEmpty()){
                        getListOfKeys(item, key+"["+index+"]",listOfKeys)
                    }else{
                        getListOfKeys(item, prefix+"."+key+"["+index+"]",listOfKeys)
                    }
                }

            }else if(value instanceof Map){

                if(prefix.isEmpty()){
                    getListOfKeys(value, key,listOfKeys)
                }else{
                    getListOfKeys(value, prefix+"."+key,listOfKeys)
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

call above method as follows

```
  def void findAllKeysInMap(){

    Map map =   [ "fields":[
            "project":
            [
                "key": "TP"
            ],
            "summary": "Api Testing Issue.",
            "description": "This issue is only for api testing purpose",
            "issuetype": [
                "name": ["Bug":["hello":[["saurabh":"gaur","om":"prakash"],                      ["gaurav":"pandey"], ["mukesh":"mishra"]]]]
            ]
        ]
    ]

            def listOfKeys=[]

            getListOfKeys(map, '', listOfKeys)

            println "listOfKeys>>>"+listOfKeys
         }
```

output:
          listOfKeys>>>[fields, fields.project, fields.project.key, fields.summary, fields.description, fields.issuetype, fields.issuetype.name, fields.issuetype.name.Bug, fields.issuetype.name.Bug.hello, fields.issuetype.name.Bug.hello[0].saurabh, fields.issuetype.name.Bug.hello[0].om, fields.issuetype.name.Bug.hello[1].gaurav, fields.issuetype.name.Bug.hello[2].mukesh]

Answer (score 0):

Slightly shorter:

```
String key = 'Address.Street'
key.split('\\.').inject(yourMap) {map, path -> map[path]}
```

If you can't guarantee that the path exists and is complete (say, if you tried to access `OrganizationName.id`) you'll need to add some safeguards (check that map is not null, and that it's really a Map)