# Create nested map from key in groovy

Tags: dictionary, gradle, groovy

I'm relatively new to groovy and am using it in the context of a gradle build. So please don't be harsh if there is an easy out-of-the-box solution for this.

Basically I'm trying to accomplish the reverse of [Return Nested Key in Groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25916607/return-nested-key-in-groovy). That is, I have some keys read from the `System.properties` map for example `user.home` and  corresponding values like `C:\User\dpr`. Now I want to create a map that reflects this structure to use it in a `groovy.text.SimpleTemplateEngine` as bindings:

```
[user : [home : 'C:\Users\dpr']]
```

The keys may define an arbitrary deep hierarchy. For example `java.vm.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation` should become:

```
[java : [vm : [spec : [vendor : 'Oracle Corporation']]]]
```

Additionally there are properties with the same parents such as `user.name=dpr` and `user.country=US`:

```
[
   user: [
     name: 'dpr',
     country: 'US'
  ]
]
```

---

**Edit**: While `ConfigSlurper` is really nice, it is somewhat too defensive with creating the nested maps as it stops nesting at the minimum depth of a certain key.

I currently ended up using this

```
def bindings = [:]
System.properties.sort().each {
  def map = bindings
  def split = it.key.split("\\.")
  for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
    def part = split[i];

    // There is already a property value with the same parent
    if (!(map instanceof Map)) {
      println "Skipping property ${it.key}"
      break;
    }

    if (!map.containsKey(part)) {
      map[part] = [:]
    }

    if (i == split.length - 1) {
      map[part] = it.value
    } else {
      map = map[part]
    }
  }
  map = it.value
}
```

With this solution the properties `file.encoding.pkg`, `java.vendor.url` and `java.vendor.url.bug` are discarded, which is not nice but something I can cope with.

However the above code is not very groovyish.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a [ConfigSlurper](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/util/ConfigSlurper.html) :

```
def conf = new ConfigSlurper().parse(System.properties)
println conf.java.specification.version
```

Comment: This seems to work partly only for some properties the correct structure is created for others not: `[java:[runtime.name:Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment, runtime.version:1.8.0_92-b14, ...`

Comment: I think this may be related to the minimum depth of a certain property path. There is `java.home` and thus it creates all `java.*` entries directly under the `java` key without further nesting.

Comment: Yes, if a.b has a value, then it can't be implemented as a map, and it can't have nested value. In this case, the ConfigSlurper create nested value with a key having a . inside. For exemple `java.vendor` is a String, so you have to access nested value with `java['vendor.url']`

Comment: I just noticed myself that for the `java.vendor`, `java.vendor.url`, `java.vendor.url.bug` and possibly others, it won't be possible to create a corresponding map. But `ConfigSlurper` seems to be a little too defensive. It could create maps for the the `java.vm.*` properties as there is no property `java.vm`. But it does not